# How to avoid /bin/sh -c /bin/bash and /bin/bash running for the same shell script?

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I have a test.sh script running in crontab every 10 minutes for the user uni-01

```
crontab -l
*/10 * * * * /bin/bash /home/uni-01/test.sh > /home/uni-01/data/_d.log 2>&1
```

When I use a `ps -eF` command the test.sh script start with `/bin/sh -c /bin/bash` and the second start with `/bin/bash` command.
How to avoid running of the `/bin/sh -c /bin/bash` command?

```
root      6007   946  0 12555  2932   1 09:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f

uni-01    6011  6007  0  1127   756   0 09:42 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash /home/uni-01/test.sh > /home/uni-01/data/_d.log 2>&1

uni-01    6019  6011  0  3164  3088   1 09:42 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/uni-01/test.sh
```

The Ubuntu release is 16.04.1 LS

Answer (score 3):

You could try including the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/bin/bash` at the start of `test.sh`.

This sets bash as your shell for the script from within the script itself, without having to spell it out explicitly in your crontab line.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [How to change cron shell (sh to bash)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash), you can change the default shell to `bash` with:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

This command has to be put anywhere before your cron line, in your case:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/10 * * * * /home/uni-01/test.sh > /home/uni-01/data/_d.log 2>&1
```

Needless to say this will affect every cron line after it, you can change it back with a `SHELL=/bin/sh` line if necessary – or just build up a `bash` section at the end of your crontab.